# SharePoint 2013 - How to disable Filter and Sort item on view?

Tags: list-view, sharepoint-server, filter, view

Is there any option to turn off or turn on "**Filter**" and "**Sort**" item on view of Share point 2013?

[image]

I update Field properties: Filterable = false; Sortable = false

It OK, but all Views of list is apply. I want do this for specific View with specific Column.

How i do that?

Comment: Most probably you will have to modify the xslt transformation or include custom JSLink to remove this functionality for single view (or to be more specific - to single webpart where this view is embedded).

Comment: yes, i can use JSLink to modify Header.
But, have any view field option for this?

Comment: Worst case scenario would be using javascript, getting header and removing buttons/actions responsible for sorting and filtering on this specific column.